# Powershell append string to text creates a new line

Tags: powershell

Im trying to create a ps script which appends the string ;history directly after ;stylesheets but currently the script is creating an additional line when i want it to append it directly after.

This is how it is suppose to look

```
;stylesheets;history
```

But this is what happens

```
;stylesheets
;history
```

Can someone explain why?

```
 (Get-Content K:\Temp\test.properties) | 
        Foreach-Object {
            $_ 
            if ($_ -match ";stylesheets") 
            {   ";history"
            }
        } | Set-Content K:\Temp\test.properties
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative solution:

```
(Get-Content K:\Temp\test.properties).Replace(';stylesheets',';stylesheets;history') |
Set-Content K:\Temp\test.properties
```

Comment: @ebrodje This is the more elegant/efficient approach. Especially since you mention that you want `;history` to always be directly after `;stylesheets`. My solution of looping with match will always put `;history` at the end of the line. In your example, those cases are the same but they may not always be.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting two lines because you are returning two objects when you match. `@($_,";history")` and each object is written as a line. You could combine them into one string when you match.

```
(Get-Content K:\Temp\test.properties) | 
    Foreach-Object {
        if ($_ -match ";stylesheets") {
            "$_;history"
        } else {
            $_
        }
    } | Set-Content K:\Temp\test.properties
```